# PhoneGap plugins, why a different Javascript part for each platform (Android, iOS)?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Regarding the coding of plugins for PhoneGap, the PhoneGap wiki says:

> Say you are developing a PhoneGap Plugin for 2 platforms: iOS and Android.
>   One might assume that we need to churn out:
>
> A single JavaScript file that will be used on both iOS and Android
>   One Java file for Android
>   One .h and One .m for iOS
>
> **However, in reality you will need to churn out**:
>
> One JavaScript file for Android, along with a Java file for Android
>   A different JavaScript file for iOS, alone with pair of .h and .m file for iOS
>
> Both JavaScript files can (and should) have the same interface for the developer who consumes it, **but the implementations of each interface would be different**.

My question is: Why should I need 2 Javascript files, for each platform one?
This is how the Javascript part of a plugin looks like:

```
var FilePlugin = function() {};
FilePlugin.prototype.read = function(data, successCallback, failureCallback) {
return PhoneGap.exec(    
        successCallback,   
        failureCallback,    
        'FilePlugin',  
        'read',              
        [data]);       
};
PhoneGap.addConstructor(function() {
PhoneGap.addPlugin("FilePlugin", new FilePlugin());
});
```

I cannot see something platform-dependent there, so why does the wiki say I need an own Javascript file for each platform?

Probably I got this wrong, so I need your help ;)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the exec API was different but they are working on making it the same, was a while since I did any PhoneGap development. And if you look at the individual pages about plugin development for [iOS](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753496/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20iOS) and [Android](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753494/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20Android) about `PhoneGap.exec` they look the same. Also note that the text on the wiki you are referring to seems to a [nearly on year old](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page-revisions/compare/36752779/PhoneGap%20Plugins?rev2=1298869821&rev1=1298744135).

Comment: Did you try if they behave the same? yeah they should probably update the wiki if so